# delete all record from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete all records from a table. My query is:

```
delete from tableName.
```

But it reports the following error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor
>   and reconnect."

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I might be missing something, but the error message already tells you what to do: *toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.*

Comment: i am using mySQL Workbench and it thorws this error.

Comment: Ok...MySQL Workbench is telling how to solve this: *toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.*. Have you tried that? If you have and it still doesn't work then flag to re-open.

Comment: There are two solutions here 1. delete from table <tablename> where 1=1 . 2. truncate <tableName>

Comment: I had this problem today and resolved it by adding a limit clause
 `delete from tableName limit 1000`, you can replace 1000 by whatever the count of the table is (`select count(*) from tableName`)

Comment: I learned there was a setting for when deleting in mysql from this not real question

Answer (score 95):

`truncate tableName`

That is what you are looking for.

Truncate [will delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) all records in the table, emptying it.

Comment: This command drops the table. It doesn't delete all the records from the table.

Comment: @mousecoder This is not correct, it will leave an empty table, where drop removes the table. Added the link to the manual.

Comment: Agree.. pardon my incorrect knowledge.

Comment: this wont work if there is FK and cascading enabled

Comment: yeah... This failed for me for the aforementioned reason

Answer (score 69):

It’s because you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

The quick fix is to add SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; before your query :

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Or

close the safe update mode.
Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> SQL Editor
remove Forbid UPDATE and DELETE statements without a WHERE clause (safe updates) .

BTW you can use  `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;` to delete all the records .

Comment: For the record, the latest version (and may be the previous ones) also fail when you use TRUNCATE TABLE.  Also, the error is still the same, however the option is in Edit->Preferencie -> SQL Queries (and not in SQL Editor).